# Задача на антипузырек

Tags: c++, алгоритм

**Ровно К обменов**

Даны два числа n и k.

Выведите перестановку из n чисел (n чисел от 1 до n без повторений) такую, чтобы сортировка пузырьком по возрастанию на соответствующем массиве сделала ровно k обменов. Если возможных ответов несколько — выведите любой.

Выведите искомую перестановку в одной строке. Числа разделяйте пробелами.

Я пытался решить, но, тестирующая система говорит что слишком долгое время выполнения. Помогите пожалуйста оптимизировать решение.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int max_size = 100;

    int arr[max_size];
    int size, swap_need;
    cin >> size >> swap_need;

    // генерация чисел
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }

    int swaps_now = 0, m = 0;
    

    // пока текущее количество swap'ов != нужному
    while (swaps_now != swap_need) {
        if (m + 1 >= size) m = 0;

        /* m нужно для отслеживания выхода за границу,
        т.е если мы выходим за границу, то просто
        начинаем менять с начала */

        swap(arr[m], arr[m + 1]);
        m++;

        // копия массива для сортировки
        int new_arr[max_size];
        for (int p = 0; p < size; p++) {
            new_arr[p] = arr[p];
        }

        // подсчет количества swap'ов в пузырьке 
        swaps_now = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= size - i; j++) {
                if (new_arr[j - 1] > new_arr[j]) {
                    swap(new_arr[j - 1], new_arr[j]);
                    swaps_now++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // вывод массива
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы можете выложить ссылку на проверяющую систему?

Comment: К сожалению, нет.

Comment: @MBo хмм а ведь и правда, и идея там такая какую, привел я.

Comment: @Павел Ериков Ух, точно такие же перестановки генерируются

Comment: Очевидное решение -- сортировать такой же функцией bubble_sort(), но по убыванию, подсчитывая количество обменов и выйти из нее по достижению `k` -- по времени не проходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На основе ответа @MBo на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1130769/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-k-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) было сделано решение на C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int max_size = 100;

    int a[max_size];
    int size, swap_need;
    cin >> size >> swap_need;

    int n = size;
    int now = 0;
    while (size > 0) {
        if (swap_need > size - 1) {
            a[now] = size;
            swap_need -= (size - 1);
            size--;
            now++;
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 1; i < size - swap_need; i++) {
                a[now] = i;
                now++;
            }
            a[now] = size;
            now++;
            for (int i = size - swap_need; i < size; i++) {
                a[now] = i;
                now++;
            }
            swap_need = 0, size = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Я не знаю ограничений, но попробуйте вот этот код:

```
int main(){
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(0);

const int max_size = 100;
int arr[max_size];
int size, swap_need;
cin >> size >> swap_need;

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    arr[i] = i + 1;

int swap_now = 0;
int k = 0;
bool isHas = false;
if (swap_need != 0) {
    for (int m = 0; m < size * size; ++m) {
        for (int i = size - 1; i > k; --i) {
            swap(arr[i], arr[i - 1]);
            ++swap_now;
            if (swap_now == swap_need) {
                isHas = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        ++k;
        if (isHas) break;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
cout << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Если он пройдет, то я опишу как он работает. Только отпишите мне об этом.

А так оказывается объяснение есть уже [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1130769/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-k-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Алгоритм, который приведен выше работает за `O(n^2)` времени.
Ниже алгоритм работающий за `O(n)` времени.

```
int main() {
const int max_size = 100;
int arr[max_size];
int size, swap_need;
cin >> size >> swap_need;

int n = size;
int j = 1;
for (int i = n; i > 0; --i) {
    if (swap_need == 0 && (j + i) == i)
        break;
    if (swap_need >= i - 1) {
        swap_need -= (i - 1);
        arr[size - i] = n--;
    }
    else arr[size - i] = j++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    cout << arr[i] << " ";

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если посмотреть на то, как числа передвигаются справа налево (лесенкой вниз или спиралью). То есть если `swap_need` будет больше `3`, то первая цифра всегда будет `5`. Если `swap_need` будет больше `6` то вторая цифра будет всегда `4`. Больше `8` то будет третьей цифрой `3`. Больше `9` то `2`, ну и единица. Надеюсь объяснил принцип.

Comment: Даны натуральное число n (n≤100) и целое неотрицательное k. Гарантируется, что для всех наборов тестовых данных решение существует.

Comment: К сожалению, ваш код уже на 3 попытке дает WA, мой код на 13 TL

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy честно вы мне немного надоели уже. Если вы знаете такой алгоритм, то пишите. Не обязательно мне об этом говорить. У меня есть идея как сделать быстрее, но пока не смог реализовать. Так что решил хотя бы такой ответ дать.

Comment: @maksim-mshp а `k` может равняться нулю? Просто я заметил что при `k = 0` не правильный ответ выводит.

Comment: Да, может. В комментарии выше я написал, целое неотрицательное число, следовательно 0 входит.

В вопросе по ссылке приведено рабочее решение, теперь мне это нужно переписать на С++ :)

Comment: @maksim-mshp хмм тогда попробуйте перед двойным циклом просто сделать проверка на `swap_need` чтобы он не был равен 0. И отпишите если пройдет.

Comment: да, добавив условие ваше решение также работает.

Comment: @maksim-mshp отлично) я даже проверяющую систему нашел и решил проверить. Уж больно интересно было